# read a file .txt in a C program

Tags: c

I am programing a parallel openmp in C language and I using this code to read one million of data from a .txt file.

```
 FILE *data = NULL;
 data = fopen("1millon.txt","r");

float ID, n, cord[1000000],cordy[1000000];
int ale = 1000000;  
for(i=0;i<ale;i++){

fscanf (data, "%f %f", &ID, &n);
    cordx[i]=ID;
    cordy[i]=n;
}
```

Actually this "fscanf" is doing well when I run my program in my normal computer. But if  I would like to run it in a cluster for parallelization it will show me the next warning **( warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  fscanf (data, "%f %f", &ID, &n);
)** 
and it won't run."

Do you know another way how to read a .txt file instead of "fscanf", "fread"?

Thanks

Comment: 1. "it won't work" is not a sufficient description of the situation. Doesn't the program compile or doesn't it run properly? 2. ID and n are declared as ints, yet your scanf treats them as floats. Pretty amazing that that went well anywhere. 3. Can you add the definition of cordx and cordy?

Comment: Don't read floats into ints - it won't go well.

Comment: printf() out the ID and n as you read them.  That's a  sorta 'standard' test/debug check.   Unless you do those sort of things, or use an actual debugger, you will not progress..

Comment: The program runs properly as sequential algorithm in my operating system, my problem is I cannot use "fscanf" for reading data  in a cluster for testing parallel programming like openmp.

Comment: It may give the impression of running properly, but your program is not **correct**. Also, does your progam fail to **compile** or **run**?

Comment: Please include a sample input from the file so it's clear what the data is supposed to look like.

Comment: You want to read the file in parallel on clusters? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf()`returns something. It is supposed to help you detect problems and special situations. Your cluster is configured to complain about that. Your own PC is not configured like that, hence it does not warn.

In order to avoid the warning on the cluster, do not ignore the return value. I.e. check whether you successfully matched.

Alternatively do `(void) fsanf...` which tells the compiler "I intentionally ignore the helpful return value.".

According to the [opengroup `fscanf` manpages](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html) (within the *RETURN VALUE* section), you should expect your call to `fscanf` to return 2 when it's successful at reading your two `float` values:

> Upon successful completion, these functions return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be 0 in the event of an early matching failure.

If it returns less than two, extra work will be required to discard erroneous input (see below for a nice example of this), exit the process or otherwise handle the error in some other manner. Otherwise, your future calls to `fscanf` will fail due to the same garbage left unread from `stdin`.

```
if (fscanf(data, "%f %f", &ID, &n) != 2) {
    fscanf(data, "%*[^\n]"); // read and discard up to the next newline character
    fgetc(data);             // ... and discard the newline character, too
    /* XXX: What to do with cordx[i] and cordy[i]? */
}
```

Comment: @Seb Thanks, good additional info. (And it probably led some reputation my way.)

Comment: Your answer is good, good enough to earn the tick in my books; no point rewriting it to add details. Besides, I don't really need the rep. I'm chasing badges atm ;)